# Subsetting index from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with columns `[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H]`.

An index has been made with columns `[D, G, H]`:

```
>>> print(dgh_columns)
Index(['D', 'G', 'H'], dtype='object')
```

How can I retrieve the original DataFrame **without** the columns `D, G, H` ?

Is there an index subset operation?

Ideally, this would be:

```
df[df.index - dgh_columns]
```

But this doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
df[df.columns.difference(dgh_columns)]
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[7,8,9],
                   'F':[1,3,5],
                   'G':[5,3,6],
                   'H':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
0  1  4  7  1  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  9  5  6  3

dgh_columns = pd.Index(['D', 'G', 'H'])
print (df[df.columns.difference(dgh_columns)])
   A  B  C  E  F
0  1  4  7  7  1
1  2  5  8  8  3
2  3  6  9  9  5
```

Numpy solution with [`numpy.setxor1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setxor1d.html) or [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html):

```
dgh_columns = pd.Index(['D', 'G', 'H'])
print (df[np.setxor1d(df.columns, dgh_columns)])
   A  B  C  E  F
0  1  4  7  7  1
1  2  5  8  8  3
2  3  6  9  9  5
```

---

```
dgh_columns = pd.Index(['D', 'G', 'H'])
print (df[np.setdiff1d(df.columns, dgh_columns)])
   A  B  C  E  F
0  1  4  7  7  1
1  2  5  8  8  3
2  3  6  9  9  5
```

Comment: Hum. Makes sense, however I get `IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds`

Comment: Please check my sample, I think I do typo before.

Comment: Okay, that's because I did perform column insertion/removal after having initialized `dgh_columns`

Comment: Anyway I'll accept your answer because it's definitely *the* answer :) I just have to figure out the details with my code

Comment: Thank you, glad can help you.

Answer (score 2):

use `drop`

```
df.drop(list('DGH'), axis=1)
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[7,8,9],
                   'F':[1,3,5],
                   'G':[5,3,6],
                   'H':[7,4,3]})

df.drop(list('DGH'), 1)
```

[image]